# How to resolve libatomic missing error, or more generally, install nodejs

Tags: software-installation, node.js

I'm trying to install node/npm (and ideally I'd like to do it with nvm) on my BananaPi, but when I run `nvm install v12.18.4`, I get the error:

```
node: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Trying to `apt install libatomic` didn't find a package.

Comment: The package is called `libatomic1`.

Comment: @NasirRiley, feel free to post an answer so I can upvote/accept.

Comment: It's posted now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package that you need isn't called `libatomic`, it's called `libatomic1`. You can install it with:

```
apt install libatomic1
```

Answer (score 1):

And for those using RedHat based distros (RHEL/CentOS/Alma/Rocky), it's

```bsh
[sudo] <yum|dnf> install libatomic
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, it said it was already the latest version, but my problem is now inexplicably fixed. All I had to do was (as root):

```
apt install libatomic1   #said it was already latest version
node                     #command not found
nvm
nvm install v12.18.4     #already installed, creating alias
node                     #works this time!
```

Now my node and npm and everything work as expected.

(if someone else wants to post a better explanation, please do and I'll accept your answer)